# Accessing Properties From Different Threads

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I have two threads that access the same set of properties, but one only reads from the properties, the other one only writes to the properties.

Which of the following properties would need to be synchronized for read operations, and which would have to be synchronized for write operations?

```
@property (nonatomic) int myInt;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger myInteger;
@property (nonatomic) CGImageRef cgImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *controller;
```

My first instinct is that everything needs to be synchronized for all read and write operations all the time.  However, since one thread is always writing and one is always reading, I'm unsure of myself.  Sure, always synchronizing is "safe" since I am unsure, but I was wondering what is actually correct?

For some reason, I have this feeling that maybe myInt and myInteger don't need to be synchronized for reads and writes since they are pass by value....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, this is what atomic properties are good at. if they were all atomic, then you could read and write without getting partially written results.

however, i've never found atomic objc properties truly useful in concurrent programs. i always result to regular locking, immutability, and so on.

although you could use atomics, it just doesn't get you very much in practical cases. they make your programs more thread *resistant* (not safe) at execution cost (both are bad, btw).

btw, pass by value is really not an issue here.

mutating a mutable value or object (e.g. reading and writing from that NSMutableArray from two threads), and maintaining the integrity of ivars which rely on each other are the primary problems.

example of maintaining the integrity of two ivars which rely on each other:

say you have two atomic properties of int type (day,month), and they have accessors. you would need more than atomics to avoid reading an invalid date (e.g. February 31st), if the reads and writes were happening from separate threads. the only way to really ensure your object is not in the middle of a partial update is to use synchronization primitives or immutable data -- this is ground atomic properties cannot save you from.

so the short answer is 'atomics', but objects in concurrent contexts are rarely so simple that  the middle ground of atomics is truly thread *safe*.

Comment: The particular example I'm going to be using in my application is that I have a float that one thread writes to and one thread reads from.  It sounds like my best bet would be to just make it atomic and not worry about synchronizing it in this situation?  In my example, the writing thread is a background thread and it will be updating its progress percentage on a process intensive task, while the reading thread is the main thread and will be updating a loading bar with the percent completed.

Comment: @MikeS if it's just an atomic `float` property and there are no dependencies or side-effects to the property change, then 'yes', that would ensure that your reads/writes to the `float` via accessor methods were never in partially written states. atomics work fine for this simple case. this would work for any POD or synthesized atomic accessor (which also performs the retain/autorelease cycle for you). that's about the extent of their utility, i've found.